# Mutate vector within filter

Tags: rust

So, I have the following code successfully performing filter in vector:

```
let mut v1 : Vec<i32> = vec!(1,2,3);
let v2 : Vec<&mut i32> = v1.iter_mut().filter(|x| {**x == 2}).collect();
println!("{:?}", v2);
```

Since the type signature of the predicate in the filter function is
`FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool`, I was assuming that that mutation inside
the closure will work:

```
let mut v1 : Vec<i32> = vec!(1,2,3);
let v2 : Vec<&mut i32> = v1.iter_mut().filter(|x| {**x = 3; **x == 2}).collect();
println!("{:?}", v2);
```

But the above code results in a compile error. How to fix that ? Note
that I'm playing with rust to get a better understanding, so the abpve
example doesn't make sense (usually, nobody will try to mutate
things inside filter).

Comment: _nobody will try to mutate things inside filter_: So that is not allowed. Maybe something like `.map(|x| *x = 3).filter(|x| *x == 2)`?

Comment: @rodrigo I'm trying to understand why that is not allowed. I though you can do mutation with `FnMut`.

Comment: @Stargateur But I'm able to mutate with `map`, for which the type is `Self::Item` which is not `mut`.

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks, that kind of helps! But I think the `rust-lang` link is broken. Can you add this as an answer with the fixed link ?

Comment: @Stargateur Changing your last example to `(a: &mut &mut i32)` makes it work as opposed to `(a : &&mut i32)`.

Comment: [`filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing two concepts: [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) means that a function can change its captured variables, like:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let mut i = 0usize;
    let v2: Vec<_> = v1
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|x| {
            i = i + 1;
            *x == 2
        })
        .collect();
    println!("We iterate {} times and produce {:?}", i, v2);
}
```

This doesn't mean that every parameter of a function will be mutable.

In your code, `filter()` takes a `&Self::Item`, which is very different from the `map()` one that takes `Self::Item`. Because the real type will translate to `Map<Item=&mut i32>` and `Filter<Item=&&mut i32>`. Rust forbids you from mutating a reference if it's behind a non mutable reference:

```rust
fn test(a: &&mut i32) {
    **a = 5;
}
```

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `**a` which is behind a `&` reference
```

This is because Rust follows the [the-rules-of-references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references):

> - At any given time, you can have either one mutable reference or any number of immutable references.
> - References must always be valid.

This means you can have more than one `&&mut` but only one `&mut &mut`. If Rust didn't stop you, you could mutate a `&&mut` and that would poison any other `&&mut`.

Unfortunately the full error description of [`E0594`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0594) is still not available, see [#61137](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61137).

Note: Avoid side effects when you use the iterator API, I think it's OK to mutate your `FnMut` state but not the item, you should do this in a for loop, like:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    for x in v1.iter_mut().filter(|x| **x == 2) {
        *x = 1;
    }
    println!("{:?}", v1);
}
```

Comment: I think in the first function you mean `iter_mut` and not `into_iter`...

Comment: This doesn't change anything

Comment: Why so ? Doesn't with `into_iter` it iterates over `T` and hence for map case the real type will be `Map<Item=i32>` as opposed to `Map<Item=&mut i32>` in the `iter_mut` case ?

Comment: Yes but in `filter()`, `T` will still be behind a reference so `&T` so not mutable. https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4a2593d6b5b3c7c56f82ef85b8801935